# Media query with image map

Tags: html, css

Why won't this media query work? I am trying to cut off the top 150px of an image map if the screen is browser width is larger than 1300 pixels. The image map is a responsive and expands the width of the browser (that part works fine).

```
<style>
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color:#cfa88a;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
img[usemap] {
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
/* on big wide screens over 1300px */
@media all and (min-width: 1300px) {
    #picmap:{margin-top:-150px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="lauout.jpg" id="picmap" alt="" width="1105" height="752" usemap="#Map" />
```

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML, and possibly a Fiddle (http://jsFiddle.net)

Comment: I modified the above to show the relevant html. The only HTML in the body it the image that is mapped and then the coordinates of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a colon in your '#picmap' styling. See:

```
#picmap:{margin-top:-150px;}
```

Should be:

```
#picmap {margin-top:-150px;}
```